# .csproj/msbuild PropertyGroup configuration for TF Build Agent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup

How can I make a project build behave different on 1) (local) compile inside Visual Studio and 2) triggered by TFS Build Server on TF Build Agent?

I tried (both without success)

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)' == 'true' AND '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' AND '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

I have (in both cases) created 2 such property groups with == and != swapped on the first condition (the one that should result in different behavior) and different content in the PropertyGroup (which is what I am really aiming for).

I am using VS 2017 and TFS 2017.

edit/update:

I found the mistake in my ways, it was that I edited the AnyCPU PropertyGoup and built x86.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent post build event in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088281/prevent-post-build-event-in-vsts)

Comment: To address your edit: **You don't need to create any environment variables**. The answer I gave uses only built-in environment variables that always exist on the build agent.

Comment: I am checking it right now. The variable is empty on desktop, but it still selects the wrong property group. Perhaps something else is off, too.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I was in the wrong propertygroup. Now I also think that above should/should have worked. At least I checked with TF_BUILD and that was working ok. Also, I noticed that I can set the condition on the property itself, not just on the propertygroup. Wondering now what to do with the question. I suppose it will get closed as duplicate? Still perhaps helpful for others to know the other msbuild macros. I could not find a reference anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreasReiff, If you want to leave this thread to help others to know the other msbuild macros, you could post the answer for this issue and mark it as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all of this works, including Daniel Mann's suggestion. I was using it on the wrong propertygroup.

Since I found this information hard to find, I hope this summary helps someone in the future.

Different property values on TF and local (VS) build can be written like

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
...
  <Optimize Condition="'$(BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)' != ''">true</Optimize>
  <Optimize Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)' != 'true'">false</Optimize>
..redundant..
  <Optimize Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'false'">true</Optimize>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```

So on TFS Build the following conditions should be true (and false in Visual Studio):

```
$(BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY) != ''
$(TF_BUILD) == 'true'
$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'
```